# Does $\sum_k \frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_k^2}$ converge if $a_k \uparrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series, cauchy-sequences

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of strictly increasing postive numbers such that $a_n \uparrow \infty$. Does $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_k^2}$$ converge?

My guess is that it converges. I tried with $a_n=n, n^2, \log n$. For all of them the series converges.

My try:

I was thinking of using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, like
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_k^2} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{a_k^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(a_k-a_{k-1})^2}{a_k^2}$$
or some other variants. But none of them works.

Then I tried to show that the series is Cauchy, i.e., for $p<q$
$$\sum_{k=p+1}^q \frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_k^2} \le \sum_{k=p+1}^q \frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_{p+1}^2}=\frac{a_q-a_p}{a_{p+1}^2}$$
but the right hand estimate does not necessarily go to zero for large $p$ and $q$. Take $a_n=n^n$ for example. But the original series converges with $a_n=n^n$.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note $a_k^2 > a_k a_{k-1}$.

Comment: I feel so stupid!

Comment: chill sayan :p
I feel stupid all the time :p

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_k^2}
&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k-a_{k-1}}{a_ka_{k-1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{a_{k-1}}-\frac1{a_k}\right)\\
&=\frac1{a_0}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MarkViola: Arin Chaudhuri's hint gives the essence, and it was first.

Comment: That's fine.  From the time stamp, they appear to have been 
contemporaneous.